# average column rows according to value in other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is the data that I am working with:

```
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dothemathonthatone/maps/master/main_test.csv")
maindf <- read.csv(text = x)

maindf_1 <- maindf %>% 
             dplyr::select(year, regional_schlüssel, age_group, fee_per_inc, fert_total, daily_hours, low_fee, middle_fee, high_fee) 

head(maindf_1)

year    regional_schlüssel  fee_per_inc fert_total  daily_hours low_fee middle_fee  high_fee
2006    12246436188 0.000000000 0.02905331  8   1   0   0
2006    12246436188 0.002770760 0.02905331  8   1   0   0
2006    12246436188 0.003857333 0.02905331  8   1   0   0
2006    12246436188 0.004237633 0.02905331  8   0   1   0
2006    12246436188 0.004482112 0.02905331  8   0   1   0
2006    12246436188 0.005085077 0.02905331  8   0   1   0
```

To prepare the data for panel regression, I want to average the non-zero values in `fee_per_inc`, the 4th column, according to the last three columns; e.g.,

```
year    regional_schlüssel  age_group   fee_per_inc fert_total  daily_hours low_fee middle_fee  high_fee
2006    12246436188 -8  0.000000000 0.02905331  8   .003314047  0   0
2006    12246436188 -8  0.002770760 0.02905331  8   .003314047  0   0
2006    12246436188 -8  0.003857333 0.02905331  8   .003314047  0   0
2006    12246436188 -8  0.004237633 0.02905331  8   0   .004601607  0
2006    12246436188 -8  0.004482112 0.02905331  8   0   .004601607  0
2006    12246436188 -8  0.005085077 0.02905331  8   0   .004601607  0
```

and then remove the zeros in the last three rows:

```
year    regional_schlüssel  age_group   fee_per_inc fert_total  daily_hours low_fee middle_fee  high_fee
2006    12246436188 -8  0.000000000 0.02905331  8   .003314047  .004601607  0
2006    12246436188 -8  0.002770760 0.02905331  8   .003314047  .004601607  0
2006    12246436188 -8  0.003857333 0.02905331  8   .003314047  .004601607  0
```

except that in this example the last row still has zeros.
After doing this I can drop `fee_per_inc`, redundant rows, and go into panel regression.

Comment: Do you need `maindf_1 %>%
  group_by(regional_schlüssel) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with('fee')), ~replace(., . != 0, mean(na.omit(.))))` ? This replaces non-zero values with `mean` of non-zero values for that column in that group.

Comment: @RonakShah thank you, but this also poses some issues when running the code. The numbers are not aggregating properly

Comment: Can you explain how you are performing the aggregation? Which columns should change with what value?

Comment: @RonakShah thank you for asking: in the first dataframe above, the average of `0.002770760` and `0.003857333` would go in the first three rows of column `low_fee`; then the average of values `0.004237633`, `0.004482112`, and `0.005085077` would go in column in `middle_fee`.

Comment: like in the last data frame in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by reshaping the data to long-format, remove rows with 0 values, grouping by `regional_schlüssel` and unique column names. We can take `mean` of non-zero `fee_per_inc` values, cast the data to wide format and remove unwanted columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


maindf_1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = ends_with('fee')) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  group_by(regional_schlüssel, grp = data.table::rleid(name)) %>%
  mutate(value =  mean(fee_per_inc[fee_per_inc != 0],  na.rm = TRUE), 
         row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_fill = list(value  =  0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp, -fee_per_inc, -row)


#    year regional_schlüssel age_group fert_total daily_hours low_fee middle_fee high_fee
#   <int>              <dbl> <fct>          <dbl> <fct>         <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0.00331    0              0
# 2  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0.00331    0              0
# 3  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0.00331    0              0
# 4  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0          0.00460        0
# 5  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0          0.00460        0
# 6  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0          0.00460        0
# 7  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0.00197    0              0
# 8  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0.00197    0              0
# 9  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0.00197    0              0
#10  2006       12246436188. -8            0.0291 8           0          0.00308        0
 # … with 9,907 more rows
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have added a `%>% unique()` and it gets closer to what I am looking for. However, do you know how I can move up the zeros, i.e., 

        `0.0291 8           0.00331    0.00460`              
        `0.0291 8           0.00331    0.00460`              
         `0.0291 8           0.00331    0.00460`

Comment: @MichaelPerdue How will you manage values in other columns then? Also what if one column has 10 0's, another has 8 how will you balance the columns?  I guess what you mean is adding `mutate_at(vars(ends_with('fee')), ~.[. != 0])` to the pipe but as you can see it returns an error because output to that is less number of rows than original `maindf_1`.

Answer (score 2):

just a newbie here, but maybe something like this?

```
maindf_2 <- maindf_1 %>% 
  mutate(fee_per_inc = ifelse(fee_per_inc==0,NA, fee_per_inc)) %>% 
  group_by(low_fee, middle_fee, high_fee) %>% 
  mutate(low_fee_avg = ifelse(low_fee !=0, mean(fee_per_inc, na.rm = T), NA),
         mid_fee_avg = ifelse(middle_fee !=0, mean(fee_per_inc, na.rm = T), NA),
         high_fee_avg = ifelse(high_fee !=0, mean(fee_per_inc, na.rm = T), NA)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-ends_with("_fee"))
```

Comment: Hello Enrico, thank you for your response. I ran the code and took a look at the output. I think there is something not quite right with the math. It might be that I also need to group_by `regional_schlüssel`.

Comment: Hey, I'm afraid I can't figure how your data must be grouped in order to get to the results you want. For the example regional_schlüssel, year and other columns displayed, I have 4 records with low_fee == 1 and fee_per_inc !=0, and their avg is not .003314047. What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: Yes, good to mention that. grouping is on age_group, year, and daily_hours.; id is regional_schlüssel.

Comment: the low_fee, middle_fee, and high_fee are quantiles of fee_per_inc, grouped by regional_schlüssel.

Comment: Awww now I see. Every group of rows is an "island" on its own, regardless of the column values. That's why in Ronan's solution rows 1-3 have a different average than rows 7-9, despite all grouping variables being equal between the 2 groups. I was just assuming every row with same grouped variables and (for example) low_fee == 1 had to be averaged together